# How could these alternate numpy `uniform` vs `random` constructions possibly differ?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray, numpy-random

I had some code that random-initialized some numpy arrays with:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
new_vectors = rng.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, target_shape).astype(np.float32)  # [-1.0, 1.0)
new_vectors /= vector_size
```

And all was working well, all project tests passing.

Unfortunately, `uniform()` returns `np.float64`, though downstream steps only want `np.float32`, and in some cases, this array is very large (think millions of 400-dimensional word-vectors). So the temporary `np.float64` return-value momentarily uses 3X the RAM necessary.

Thus, I replaced the above with what definitionally should be equivalent:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
new_vectors = rng.random(target_shape, dtype=np.float32)  # [0.0, 1.0)                                                 
new_vectors *= 2.0  # [0.0, 2.0)                                                                                  
new_vectors -= 1.0  # [-1.0, 1.0)
new_vectors /= vector_size
```

And after this change, all closely-related functional tests still pass, but a single distant, fringe test relying on far-downstream calculations from the vectors so-initialized has started failing. And failing in a very reliable way. It's a stochastic test, and passes with large margin-for-error in top case, but always fails in bottom case. So: something has changed, but in some very subtle way.

The superficial values of `new_vectors` seem properly and similarly distributed in both cases. And again, all the "close-up" tests of functionality still pass.

So I'd love theories for what non-intuitive changes this 3-line change may have made that could show up far-downstream.

(I'm still trying to find a minimal test that detects whatever's different. If you'd enjoy doing a deep-dive into the affected project, seeing the exact close-up tests that succeed & one fringe test that fails, and commits with/without the tiny change, at https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2944#issuecomment-704512389. But really, I'm just hoping a numpy expert might recognize some tiny corner-case where something non-intuitive happens, or offer some testable theories of same.)

Any ideas, proposed tests, or possible solutions?

Comment: I'm no numpy expert but a numpy noob, but I'd suspect the first version to have a few more bits. [Try this](https://repl.it/repls/BasicAmbitiousComputerscience#main.py)

Comment: That's a super-interesting demonstration of some difference that persists even though the arrays are superficially the same `dtype`, with similar values. Thanks! Can you see my further changes on that `repl.it`? Why would a `float32` down-cast from `float64` retain more least-significant bits? (Also, I'm not sure any of my downstream calcs should be sensitive to those far-tiny bits, in the direction of performing worse without them, but as a tangible difference between the two codepaths, I'll keep looking into it as a possible cause.)

Comment: (Here's my slightly-altered version: https://repl.it/repls/PowerfulFavorablePi - I may be digging into numpy source before this is done. The observation below, that one path is only generating every-other number, interesting. I suppose turning the raw bits into properly-ranged number truncates slightly more bits, from 32, than from 64. Maybe?)

Comment: I don't think the seeds or that "every other" play a role. That just gives you different numbers of the same quality, not a different quality. Why *wouldn't* float32 from float64 retain more bits? It can retain 24 significant bits, and the float64 has plenty more than that. Let's say you produce the float64 0.000000000011111111111111111111 (in binary). The float32-rng could never produce that, but the float64-rng can, and converting to float32 keeps it all.

Comment: I'm sure you're on to something. But, underlying source of random bits is same in both cases. And there's obviously some giant overlap in the interpretation, given how the floats in positions (0,1,2..) of the float64 stream are, except in their least-significant-bits, equal to the floats in positions (1,3,5...) of the float32 generation. Seems very-1st 32 bits from the generator becomes a full float32 in float32 case, but just least-sig bits in the float64 case (sensible to me). But then, even downcast of float64 to 32 bits retains some of those other-32 (which is a little surprising).

Comment: In any case, I hope this *isn't* the cause of my test failure, because I want to be able to rely on randoms that were only ever `float32` - not being forced to generate 64bits of randomness just to get a `float32` that's sufficient.

Comment: The retaining of more bits shouldn't surprise. And the thing is, in our demos, all the numbers produced by your first way that don't end up as `.0` *cannot* be produced by the float32-rng. If it could, it would be biased.

Comment: Not sure how that 'biased' conclusion follows. Couldn't any possible non `.0` values appear in a way maintaining uniformity? And if not, would it then follow that the mere act of taking the 'uniform' `float64` values and downcasting to `float32` ruins their uniformity? In that case: which would we expect to be "most uniform" - `rng.uniform(0.0, 1.0, (1))`, `rng.uniform(0.0, 1.0, (1)).astype(np.float32)`, `rng.random(1)`, or `rng.random(1, dtype=np.float32)`? (I'd hope in practical use my consumers would be robust to the slight differences, but your comment about bias makes me curious.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer with full details on the precision/uniformity interaction here. Ultimately it turned out that my downstream test *wasn't* sensitive to least-significant-bits, but rather was insufficiently robust against `seed` choices. The alternate `float32` random stream just happened to toggle the `seed` from bing lucky, to unlucky, for the distant test. And the fact that I was still seeing jitter in the margin-of-passing on re-runs, from *other* randomness in the test, initially blinded me to the seed's primary role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code with the following values:

```
seed = 0
target_shape = [100]
vector_size = 3
```

I noticed that the code in your first solution generated a different new_vectors then your second solution.

Specifically it looks like `uniform` keeps half of the values from the random number generator that `random` does with the same seed. This is probably because of an implementation detail within the random generator from numpy.

In the following snippet i only inserted spaces to align similar values. there is probably also some float rounding going on making the result appear not identical.

```
[            0.09130779,              -0.15347552,             -0.30601767,              -0.32231492,              0.20884682, ...]
[0.23374946, 0.09130772, 0.007424275, -0.1534756, -0.12811375, -0.30601773, -0.28317323, -0.32231498, -0.21648853, 0.20884681, ...]
```

Based on this i speculate that your stochastic test case only tests your solution with one seed and because you generate a different sequence with the new solution. and this result causes a failure in the test case.

Comment: These are great observations, thanks! (Including how downcast essentially discards half the raw random bits.) And yes, the failing test has some constant seeding, but there are also other sources of non-seeded randomness in each runs, so repeated runs show some expected of jitter - though the 'fail' case is always far outside the tolerance, and the 'succeed' case always within. I've now tried a handful of alt-seeds in the 'succeed' case, & can't make it fail, but among a handful of alt-seeds in the 'fail' case, a couple have succeeded. So now going to dive deeper into influence of seeds.

Comment: While I learned more from the other answers – which were all highly responsive to my "what might cause such difference" query – it turns out that it *was* a problem with the (flimsy) test using a `seed` that was lucky for the `float64`derived stream, and unlucky for the `float32` stream. Trying a range of seeds revealed about a 20-30% failure in either case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's print `new_vectors * 2**22 % 1` for both methods, i.e., let's look at what's left after the first 22 fractional bits (program is at the end). With the first method:

```
[[0.         0.5        0.25       0.         0.        ]
 [0.5        0.875      0.25       0.         0.25      ]
 [0.         0.25       0.         0.5        0.5       ]
 [0.6875     0.328125   0.75       0.5        0.52539062]
 [0.75       0.75       0.25       0.375      0.25      ]]
```

With the second method:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Quite a difference! The second method doesn't produce any numbers with 1-bits after the first 22 fractional bits.

Let's imagine we had a type `float3` which could only hold *three* significant bits (think span of non-zero bits), so for example the numbers (in binary) 1.01 or 11100.0 or 0.0000111, but not 10.01 because that has *four* significant bits.

Then the random number generator for the range [0, 1) would pick from these eight numbers:

```
0.000
0.001
0.010
0.011
0.100
0.101
0.110
0.111
```

Wait, hold on. Why only from those eight? What about for example the aforementioned 0.0000111? That's in [0, 1) and can be represented, right?

Well yes, but note that that's in [0, 0.5). And there are *no* further representable numbers in the range [0.5, 1), as those numbers all start with "0.1" and thus any further 1-bits can only be at the second or third fractional bit. For example 0.1001 would not be representable, as that has *four* significant bits.

So if the generator would also pick from any other than those eight numbers above, they'd all have to be in [0, 0.5), creating a bias. It could pick from *different* four numbers in that range instead, or possibly include *all* representable numbers in that range with proper probabilities, but either way you'd have a "gap bias", where numbers picked from [0, 0.5) can have smaller or larger gaps than numbers picked from [0.5, 1). Not sure "gap bias" is a thing or the correct term, but the point is that the distribution in [0, 0.5) would look different than that in [0.5, 1). The only way to make them look the same is if you stick with picking from those equally-spaced eight numbers above. The distribution/possibilities in [0.5, 1) dictate what you should use in [0, 0.5).

So... a random number generator for `float3` would pick from those eight numbers and never generate for example 0.0000111. But now imagine we also had a type `float5`, which could hold *five* significant bits. Then a random number generator for that could pick 0.00001. And if you then convert that to our `float3`, that would survive, you'd have 0.00001 as `float3`. But in the range [0.5, 1), this process of generating `float5` numbers and converting them to `float3` would still only produce the numbers 0.100, 0.101, 0.110 and 0.111, since `float3` still can't represent any other numbers in that range.

So that's what you get, just with `float32` and `float64`. Your two methods give you different distributions. I'd say the second method's distribution is actually better, as the first method has what I called "gap bias". So maybe it's not your new method that's broken, but the test. If that's the case, fix the test. Otherwise, an idea to fix your situation might be to use the old `float64`-to-`float32` way, but not produce everything at once. Instead, prepare the `float32` structure with just 0.0 everywhere, and then fill it in smaller chunks generated with your new way.

Small caveat, btw: Looks like there's a [bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17478) in NumPy for generating random `float32` values, not using the lowest-position bit. So that might be another reason the test fails. You could try your second method with `(rng.integers(0, 2**24, target_shape) / 2**24).astype(np.float32)` instead of `rng.random(target_shape, dtype=np.float32)`. I think that's equivalent to what the fixed version would be (since it's apparently currently doing it that way, except with 23 instead of 24).

The program for the experiment at the top (also [at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BasicAmbitiousComputerscience#main.py)):

```
import numpy as np

# Some setup
seed = 13
target_shape = (5, 5)
vector_size = 1

# First way
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
new_vectors = rng.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, target_shape).astype(np.float32)  # [-1.0, 1.0)
new_vectors /= vector_size

print(new_vectors * 2**22 % 1)

# Second way
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
new_vectors = rng.random(target_shape, dtype=np.float32)  # [0.0, 1.0)                                                 
new_vectors *= 2.0  # [0.0, 2.0)                                                                                  
new_vectors -= 1.0  # [-1.0, 1.0)
new_vectors /= vector_size

print(new_vectors * 2**22 % 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a spectacular explanation of – & examples for – why the lower-precision generator won't use all bits. And, it seems any slight bias from downcasting the higher-precision is of roughly the same class as "floats can't represent all numbers", and only on the order of the tiny smallest-possible-increment deviations - rather than the larger bias that using more least-significant-bits in a natively-lower-precision generator would create. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A way to maintain precision and conserve memory could be to create your large target array, then fill it in using blocks at higher precision.

For example:

```py
def generate(shape, value, *, seed=None, step=10):
  arr = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.float32)
  rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
  (d0, *dr) = shape
  for i in range(0, d0, step):
    j = min(d0, i + step)
    arr[i:j,:] = rng.uniform(-1/value, 1/value, size=[j-i]+dr)
  return arr
```

which can be used as:

```py
generate((100, 1024, 1024), 7, seed=13)
```

You can tune the size of these blocks (via `step`) to maintain performance.

Comment: Very nice. I had the same basic idea (fill in chunks), but as numpy noob I didn't try implementing it :-). Do you think it's a good idea to "maintain" that precision, though, given that it's more maintained for the numbers closer to zero? In my answer I argue against it, and numpy's generators also don't do that (though that *could* be for efficiency, as I imagine a properly weighted distribution would be more complicated and slower).

Comment: guess it depends on how much the OP cares about their LSBs.  they'd have to be pretty careful with what they're doing for it to matter, but maybe!  I think your answer is correct about what's going on, but I'm struggling to follow the explanation. (http://prng.di.unimi.it/ has some good info about generating full precision floats at the end of the document)